# Non linear transformation of svg in python

Tags: python, svg, vector-graphics

I want to do a non-linear transformation of a svg in python. My specific problem is to transform a rectangular svg image into a frustum like image, for which i have a mathematical equation of the form (x',y') = f(x,y).

So far, I've been able to find a javascript library called warp.js (https://github.com/benjamminf/warpjs), which supports application of generic point-wise transformation on svg. But I'm unable to find any such tools for python except for basic transformation like skew, rotation etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image]